# PHP-mysql: using radio buttons in searching

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a database for a college, using php and mysql; however i want to be able to search entries. So far I can search "text" information such as "name" and "project description"; but cant get the radio buttons to search students by gender: M or F.

The search form is below:

```
<tr><td><?php _e("Home university");?>:</td><td><input type="text" name="place" value="<?php echo cG("place");?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php _e("Supervisor Name");?>:</td><td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo cG("title");?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php _e("Project Description Keyword");?>:</td><td><input type="text" name="desc" value="<?php echo cG("desc");?>" /></td></tr>
```

The form in which the information is being input:

```
if (strlen(cG("title"))>=MIN_SEARCH_CHAR){
    $filter.= " and p.title like '%".cG("title")."%' ";
    $order="p.insertDate Desc";
    $advs=true;
}

if (strlen(cG("desc"))>=MIN_SEARCH_CHAR){
    $filter.= " and p.description like '%".cG("desc")."%' ";
    $order="p.insertDate Desc";
    $advs=true;
}
```

Comment: I find this code unreadable.

Comment: Details like table description etc..

Comment: I doubt `cG()` and `_e()` are from the standard library. Could you give them more meaningful names or provide their definition?

Comment: I cannot see any radio buttons in the form snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to read your code and gave my guess.

This should work or at least be the solution or clue, depending on what job the function "cG" does. But you still need to change the some content to fit your MySQL table definition and debug it.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    Gender
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" <?php if(cG("gender") == "Male") echo "checked=\"checked\" ";?>/>Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php if(cG("gender") == "Female") echo "checked=\"checked\" ";?>/>Female
  </td>
</tr>
```

In your PHP script:

```
if (strlen(cG("gender")) >= 4){
  $filter.= " and YOUR_GENDER_COLUMN_NAME_IN_TABLE = '".cG("gender")."' ";
  $order="p.insertDate Desc";
  $advs=true;
}
```

Well remember to check your user input to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: Adrian Hou, you ROCK!! simply the best, and works like a charm. add me to your network!